# Compile the Ubuntu “Raring” Kernel with the Intel Compiler

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiling, linux-kernel, gcc

Of course, the first question is: why I'm doing this. Just for fun! I'm learning more about Linux kernels and I have a virtual machine that I can replace in 15 minutes.

Getting to business, I don't know how to do this, so I went to trying to edit the makefile (trying to learn). So I started with the makefile in the path `ubuntu-raring/Makefile`, which is the main make file; can be found under this link:

http://pastebin.com/ms2WpQi7

And there I changed every `gcc` to `icc`, and every `g++` to `icpc`, and every `-O2` to `-O3`. The result is the following:

http://pastebin.com/cSwTYJ9C

I followed the instructions from this site, too:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

But eventually, I'm getting weird errors that seem to be caused by using `gcc`/`g++` rather than `icc`/`icpc`. For example, I got an error in the file `ubuntu-raring/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h` that some macros are already defined, while this file shouldn't be included in the first place! The macro that includes it is in the file `ubuntu-raring/include/linux/compiler.h`, and looks like:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#include <linux/compiler-gcc.h>
#endif

/* Intel compiler defines __GNUC__. So we will overwrite implementations
 * coming from above header files here
 */
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
# include <linux/compiler-intel.h>
#endif
```

And while I don't understand the comment written above the Intel header (sounds weird... why would you define implementations then overwrite them? Never done that in C++!), removing the include of the `gcc` header manually solved the problem, but other problems came up, and I have no idea whether they're related.

So now I'm confused! What did I do wrong? And should changing every `gcc` and `g++` in the Makefile be sufficient to use a different compiler? Or are there other things to be changed that I overlooked?

Thank you for any efforts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
First learn to walk, then learn to fly.
```

If you want to learn, read. Have you read [this instruction manual for building the kernel with the Intel C compiler](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/146679/linuxkernelbuildwhitepaper.pdf)? It's a rethorical question b/c this manual uses a different approach to choosing `icc` over `gcc`.

You are doing three things at once:

- fiddle with some adopted and patched kernel to fit into the Ubuntu world (which is gcc)
- Up the optimization from `-O2` to `-O3`.
- change the compiler

Start out with a vanilla Linux kernel from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org). Keep everything standard and figure out how to build a kernel that works for your computer. Build a kernel that has only the drivers your computer needs, nothing more. Once you can compile and boot into your own kernel, you can start changing the build environment.

Going from `-O2` to `-O3` will probably never work. `-O3` is like opening Pandora's box. If enabling `-O3` was that easy, it would probably be the default!

Comment: Thank you so much. I will follow those instructions, and you get a +1, unless this is the best answer, then you get the big check mark soon :)